# Login Form disappear after loading new language pack and select it -SuiteCrm

Tags: suitecrm

I installed SuiteCrm and after loaded and installed new language pack,
and select the required language in the login combobox and then  my "Login" just disappear and when I inspect on the empty area its show me like I am using Explorer browser with wrong version even that I am using Chrome.

Comment: Which SuiteCRM version is this?

Comment: SuiteCRM 7.10.7

Comment: Thanks. And exactly which language pack were you using? If you use the latest versions of SuiteCRM, and of the Language Pack, does this problem still happen?

Answer (score 1):

To fix that bug you should edit this file:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\xfeet\themes\SuiteP\tpls\login.tpl
```

remove the lines:

```
<span class="error" id="ie_compatibility_mode_warning" style="display:none">
    {sugar_translate label="WARN_BROWSER_IE_COMPATIBILITY_MODE_WARNING"}

    <span class="error" id="browser_warning" style="display:none">
        {sugar_translate label="WARN_BROWSER_VERSION_WARNING"}
```

That should fix it